# Using Sympy in for loop error: "Sympify error"

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to use the sympy equation solver within a for loop in python but keep receiving "Sympify error." When I use just one value for the dependent variable, it seems to work...

This Works:

```
import sympy as sym

beta=0.98
gama = 0.75
kappa = 0.5
Tau = 0.5
lam = ((Tau)/beta - 1 )*mu


L, mu = sym.symbols('L, mu')
f = sym.Eq(L**(1+gama)-mu/kappa, 0)
g = sym.Eq(mu+kappa*lam-kappa, 0)

print(sym.solve([f,g], (L, mu)))
```

This does not work:

```
import sympy as sym

beta=0.98
gama = 0.75
kappa = 0.5
Tau = np.linspace(beta,2.0,100)
n = len(Tau)
lam = ((Tau)/beta - 1 )*mu
Results = [ ] 
for element in Tau:
    L, mu = sym.symbols('L, mu')
    f = sym.Eq(L**(1+gama)-mu/kappa, 0)
    g = sym.Eq(mu+kappa*lam-kappa, 0)
    Results = sym.solve([f,g], (L, mu))
```

As you can probably tell by the simplicity of this code, I'm a novice to python. Thanks in advance!

Error:

```
SympifyError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/3w/rf05gzwx7hg_6z0yb_bxsvv00000gn/T/ipykernel_15637/3090886173.py in <module>
     11     L, mu = sym.symbols('L, mu')
     12     f = sym.Eq(L**(1+gama)-mu/kappa, 0)
---> 13     g = sym.Eq(mu+kappa*lam-kappa, 0)
     14     Results = sym.solve([f,g], (L, mu))
     15 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __new__(cls, lhs, rhs, **options)
    501             rhs = 0
    502         evaluate = options.pop('evaluate', global_parameters.evaluate)
--> 503         lhs = _sympify(lhs)
    504         rhs = _sympify(rhs)
    505         if evaluate:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py in _sympify(a)
    503 
    504     """
--> 505     return sympify(a, strict=True)
    506 
    507 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py in sympify(a, locals, convert_xor, strict, rational, evaluate)
    431 
    432     if strict:
--> 433         raise SympifyError(a)
    434 
    435     if iterable(a):

SympifyError: SympifyError: array([mu - 0.5, 1.00525664811379*mu - 0.5, 1.01051329622758*mu - 0.5,
       1.01576994434137*mu - 0.5, 1.02102659245516*mu - 0.5,
       1.02628324056895*mu - 0.5, 1.03153988868275*mu - 0.5,
       1.03679653679654*mu - 0.5, 1.04205318491033*mu - 0.5,
       1.04730983302412*mu - 0.5, 1.05256648113791*mu - 0.5,
       1.0578231292517*mu - 0.5, 1.06307977736549*mu - 0.5,
       1.06833642547928*mu - 0.5, 1.07359307359307*mu - 0.5,
       1.07884972170686*mu - 0.5, 1.08410636982066*mu - 0.5,
       1.08936301793445*mu - 0.5, 1.09461966604824*mu - 0.5,
       1.09987631416203*mu - 0.5, 1.10513296227582*mu - 0.5,
       1.11038961038961*mu - 0.5, 1.1156462585034*mu - 0.5,
       1.12090290661719*mu - 0.5, 1.12615955473098*mu - 0.5,
       1.13141620284477*mu - 0.5, 1.13667285095857*mu - 0.5,
       1.14192949907236*mu - 0.5, 1.14718614718615*mu - 0.5,
       1.15244279529994*mu - 0.5, 1.15769944341373*mu - 0.5,
       1.16295609152752*mu - 0.5, 1.16821273964131*mu - 0.5,
       1.1734693877551*mu - 0.5, 1.17872603586889*mu - 0.5,
       1.18398268398268*mu - 0.5, 1.18923933209647*mu - 0.5,
       1.19449598021027*mu - 0.5, 1.19975262832406*mu - 0.5,
       1.20500927643785*mu - 0.5, 1.21026592455164*mu - 0.5,
       1.21552257266543*mu - 0.5, 1.22077922077922*mu - 0.5,
       1.22603586889301*mu - 0.5, 1.2312925170068*mu - 0.5,
       1.23654916512059*mu - 0.5, 1.24180581323438*mu - 0.5,
       1.24706246134818*mu - 0.5, 1.25231910946197*mu - 0.5,
       1.25757575757576*mu - 0.5, 1.26283240568955*mu - 0.5,
       1.26808905380334*mu - 0.5, 1.27334570191713*mu - 0.5,
       1.27860235003092*mu - 0.5, 1.28385899814471*mu - 0.5,
       1.2891156462585*mu - 0.5, 1.29437229437229*mu - 0.5,
       1.29962894248609*mu - 0.5, 1.30488559059988*mu - 0.5,
       1.31014223871367*mu - 0.5, 1.31539888682746*mu - 0.5,
       1.32065553494125*mu - 0.5, 1.32591218305504*mu - 0.5,
       1.33116883116883*mu - 0.5, 1.33642547928262*mu - 0.5,
       1.34168212739641*mu - 0.5, 1.3469387755102*mu - 0.5,
       1.352195423624*mu - 0.5, 1.35745207173779*mu - 0.5,
       1.36270871985158*mu - 0.5, 1.36796536796537*mu - 0.5,
       1.37322201607916*mu - 0.5, 1.37847866419295*mu - 0.5,
       1.38373531230674*mu - 0.5, 1.38899196042053*mu - 0.5,
       1.39424860853432*mu - 0.5, 1.39950525664811*mu - 0.5,
       1.4047619047619*mu - 0.5, 1.4100185528757*mu - 0.5,
       1.41527520098949*mu - 0.5, 1.42053184910328*mu - 0.5,
       1.42578849721707*mu - 0.5, 1.43104514533086*mu - 0.5,
       1.43630179344465*mu - 0.5, 1.44155844155844*mu - 0.5,
       1.44681508967223*mu - 0.5, 1.45207173778602*mu - 0.5,
       1.45732838589981*mu - 0.5, 1.46258503401361*mu - 0.5,
       1.4678416821274*mu - 0.5, 1.47309833024119*mu - 0.5,
       1.47835497835498*mu - 0.5, 1.48361162646877*mu - 0.5,
       1.48886827458256*mu - 0.5, 1.49412492269635*mu - 0.5,
       1.49938157081014*mu - 0.5, 1.50463821892393*mu - 0.5,
       1.50989486703772*mu - 0.5, 1.51515151515152*mu - 0.5,
       1.52040816326531*mu - 0.5], dtype=object)
```

Comment: What kind of error does it give?

Comment: SympifyError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/3w/rf05gzwx7hg_6z0yb_bxsvv00000gn/T/ipykernel_15637/3090886173.py in <module>
     11     L, mu = sym.symbols('L, mu')
     12     f = sym.Eq(L**(1+gama)-mu/kappa, 0)
---> 13     g = sym.Eq(mu+kappa*lam-kappa, 0)
     14     Results = sym.solve([f,g], (L, mu))
     15 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __new__(cls, lhs, rhs, **options)
    501             rhs = 0

Comment: plz add this error in question?It is not clear here.

Comment: I just added it